# Using the same onTouchEvent in various Activity

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am using an `onTouchEvent` for in my `MainActivity.class`. It's working fine : if the user make a double L with the fingers, I call a fragment.
I would like to use this `onTouchEvent` in an other `Activity` but I think it's dirty if I copy all my code.

Now for that I have created an implement `TouchListenerImpl` for that :

```
class TouchListenerImpl implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private boolean movingDownL, movingDownR, movingLeft, movingRight, movingSuccessL, movingSuccessR = false;
    private Point oldCoordsL, oldCoordsR, startPointL, startPointR = new Point(0, 0);
    private boolean admin_touch = false;
    private OnLTouch callback;

    void setCallback(OnLTouch c) {
        callback = c;
    }

    interface OnLTouch {
        void lTouchSuccess();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Log.d("debugTouch", "onTouch");

        int pIndexL = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(0));
        int pIndexR = 0;

        if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) pIndexR = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(1));

        if(event.getPointerCount() > 1 && event.getX(pIndexL) > event.getX(pIndexR)) {
            int tmp = pIndexR;
            pIndexR = pIndexL;
            pIndexL = tmp;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                movingDownL = true;
                movingDownR = true;
                movingSuccessL = false;
                movingSuccessR = false;

                if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    startPointR = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexR), (int) event.getY(pIndexR));
                    oldCoordsR = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexR), (int) event.getY(pIndexR));
                }

                startPointL = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexL), (int) event.getY(pIndexL));
                oldCoordsL = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexL), (int) event.getY(pIndexL));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int downMinDistance = 300;
                int lnrInaccuracy = 10;
                int downInaccuracy = 30;
                if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    if(!movingDownR) {
                        if(Math.abs(oldCoordsR.x - event.getX(pIndexR)) < downInaccuracy &&
                                oldCoordsR.y < event.getY(pIndexR)) break;
                        if(Math.abs(oldCoordsR.y - event.getY(pIndexR)) < lnrInaccuracy &&
                                oldCoordsR.x > event.getX(pIndexR) && !movingRight) {
                            movingRight = true;
                            startPointR = new Point(new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR)));
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (Math.abs(oldCoordsR.x - event.getX(pIndexR)) > downInaccuracy ||
                                oldCoordsR.y < event.getY(pIndexR)) {
                            movingDownR = false;
                            break;
                        } else if(findDistance(startPointR,
                                new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR))) >= downMinDistance){
                            movingDownR = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(!movingDownL) {
                    if(Math.abs(oldCoordsL.x - event.getX(pIndexL)) < downInaccuracy &&
                            oldCoordsL.y < event.getY(pIndexL)) break;
                    if(Math.abs(oldCoordsL.y - event.getY(pIndexL)) < lnrInaccuracy &&
                            oldCoordsL.x < event.getX(pIndexL) && !movingLeft) {
                        movingLeft = true;
                        startPointL = new Point(new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL)));
                    }
                }else {
                    if (Math.abs(oldCoordsL.x - event.getX(pIndexL)) > downInaccuracy ||
                            oldCoordsL.y > event.getY(pIndexL)) {
                        movingDownL = false;
                        break;
                    } else if(findDistance(startPointL,
                            new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL))) >= downMinDistance){
                        movingDownL = false;
                    }
                }

                int lnrMinDistance = 50;
                if(movingLeft) {
                    if (Math.abs(oldCoordsL.y - event.getY(pIndexL)) > lnrInaccuracy ||
                            oldCoordsL.x > event.getX(pIndexL)) {
                        movingLeft = false;
                        break;
                    } else if(findDistance(startPointL,
                            new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL))) >= lnrMinDistance) {
                        movingLeft = false;
                        movingSuccessL = true;
                    }
                }

                if(movingRight) {
                    if (Math.abs(oldCoordsR.y - event.getY(pIndexR)) > lnrInaccuracy ||
                            oldCoordsR.x < event.getX(pIndexR)) {
                        movingRight = false;
                        break;
                    } else if(findDistance(startPointR,
                            new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR))) >= lnrMinDistance) {
                        movingRight = false;
                        movingSuccessR = true;
                    }
                }

                if(movingSuccessL && movingSuccessR) {
                    if (!admin_touch)
                    {
                        admin_touch = true;

                        if (callback != null)
                            callback.lTouchSuccess();
                    }
                }

                oldCoordsL = new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL));
                oldCoordsR = new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR));

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                movingDownL = false;
                movingDownR = false;
                movingLeft = false;
                movingRight = false;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private double findDistance(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
    }
}
```

In my Activity, I call the implement like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    TouchListenerImpl imp = new TouchListenerImpl();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imp.setCallback(new TouchListenerImpl.OnLTouch() {
            @Override
            public void lTouchSuccess() {
                Log.d("debugTouch", "WORKING !");         
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("debugTouch", "onTouch");
        return imp.onTouch(v, event);
    }
}
```

The problem is I never enter in my logs. It's not working at all...

Comment: Who got the bounty?

Comment: really sorry... I wait so much time so the bounty have expired... I'm really sorry :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use @DrilonBlakqori solution with little modification.

Make a separate class containing common code but use a callback to make `View` visible.

```
class TouchListenerImpl implements OnTouchListener {
    private OnLTouch callback;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // all your code
        ...
            if (callback != null)
                callback.lTouchSuccess();
        ...
    }

    void setCallback(OnLTouch c) {
        callback = c;
    }

    interface OnLTouch {
        void lTouchSuccess();
    }
}
```

In your `MainActivity`, create a new instance of `TouchListenerImpl` and `setCallback` like

```
TouchListenerImpl imp = new TouchListenerImpl();
imp.setCallback(new OnLTouch() {
    public void lTouchSuccess() {
        frameLayoutAdmin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.framelayout_admin,new AdminLoginFragment())
            .commit();
        img_close.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

And in `MainActivity`, the `View` on which you want to detect the *double L* on that `View` set this listener on that `View`.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(imp);
```

I assume you want to detect *double L* on the main layout. For that you can do

```
findViewById(R.id.mylayout).setOnTouchListener(imp);
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks but when I touch the screen, it never pass in the onTouch of TouchListenerImpl.

Comment: @Jéwôm' You need to override `onTouch` in `MainActivity` and call `imp.onTouch(v, event)` in there.

Comment: I edit my answer thanks to your response. But It still not working. Look at my code please :)

Comment: So even `debugTouch: inTouch` is not getting displayed in logs?

Comment: It is because you are not setting the listener on any `View`.

Comment: Where I have to do that ? in the onTouch ? how ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You need not override `onTouch` in `MainActivity` if you do `view.setOnTouchListener(imp)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You help me a lot these days :) I give you the bounty!

Comment: Sorry I have to wait 22 hours before give you !

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks. I m really excited for my first bounty award.

Comment: When do I get the bounty?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a super class Activity, override onTouchEvent there and extend from it.
Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Your implementation.
}

}
```

And then your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

}
```

Comment: Thanks but how I can declare my frameLayoutAdmin and my img_close ? (I use it for change the visibility)

Comment: What about changing that Fragment for a DialogFragment? So that you wouldn't need to depend on a container to add the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a superclass that extends activity and implements your onTouchEvent method and in any activity you want to use the onTouchEvent method extend your superclass. MainActivity would have to extend it as well. Or just extend MainActivity in other activities where you want to use your onTouchEvent method.

Comment: I have updated my question using this method, but it still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Copy all your code together with the field variables to a class which implements the `OnTouchListener`. Then just pass a new `TouchListenerImpl`  whenever you need it.

```
class TouchListenerImpl implements OnTouchListener {

    // your field variables

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // all your code
        return false;
    }

    // getters for the variables that you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how I can declare my frameLayoutAdmin and my img_close ? (I use it for change the visibility)

Comment: I have updated my question using this method, but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the listener in the activity's root, and you need to keep attention to your view hierarchy. Touch events can be consumed by other views in the hierarchy, which can be the reason you aren't getting any logs.

I tested your listener with minimal changes, and I got the logs. I got the double L touch once.

```
public class TouchListenerImpl implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private boolean movingDownL, movingDownR, movingLeft, movingRight, movingSuccessL, movingSuccessR = false;
    private Point oldCoordsL, oldCoordsR, startPointL, startPointR = new Point(0, 0);
    private boolean admin_touch = false;
    private OnLTouch callback;

    public TouchListenerImpl(OnLTouch callback){
        setCallback(callback);
    }

    void setCallback(OnLTouch c) {
        callback = c;
    }

    public interface OnLTouch {
        void lTouchSuccess();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Log.d("debugTouch", "onTouch");

        int pIndexL = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(0));
        int pIndexR = 0;

        if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) pIndexR = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(1));

        if(event.getPointerCount() > 1 && event.getX(pIndexL) > event.getX(pIndexR)) {
            int tmp = pIndexR;
            pIndexR = pIndexL;
            pIndexL = tmp;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                movingDownL = true;
                movingDownR = true;
                movingSuccessL = false;
                movingSuccessR = false;

                if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    startPointR = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexR), (int) event.getY(pIndexR));
                    oldCoordsR = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexR), (int) event.getY(pIndexR));
                }

                startPointL = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexL), (int) event.getY(pIndexL));
                oldCoordsL = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexL), (int) event.getY(pIndexL));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int downMinDistance = 300;
                int lnrInaccuracy = 10;
                int downInaccuracy = 30;
                if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    if(!movingDownR) {
                        if(Math.abs(oldCoordsR.x - event.getX(pIndexR)) < downInaccuracy &&
                                oldCoordsR.y < event.getY(pIndexR)) break;
                        if(Math.abs(oldCoordsR.y - event.getY(pIndexR)) < lnrInaccuracy &&
                                oldCoordsR.x > event.getX(pIndexR) && !movingRight) {
                            movingRight = true;
                            startPointR = new Point(new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR)));
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (Math.abs(oldCoordsR.x - event.getX(pIndexR)) > downInaccuracy ||
                                oldCoordsR.y < event.getY(pIndexR)) {
                            movingDownR = false;
                            break;
                        } else if(findDistance(startPointR,
                                new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR))) >= downMinDistance){
                            movingDownR = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(!movingDownL) {
                    if(Math.abs(oldCoordsL.x - event.getX(pIndexL)) < downInaccuracy &&
                            oldCoordsL.y < event.getY(pIndexL)) break;
                    if(Math.abs(oldCoordsL.y - event.getY(pIndexL)) < lnrInaccuracy &&
                            oldCoordsL.x < event.getX(pIndexL) && !movingLeft) {
                        movingLeft = true;
                        startPointL = new Point(new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL)));
                    }
                }else {
                    if (Math.abs(oldCoordsL.x - event.getX(pIndexL)) > downInaccuracy ||
                            oldCoordsL.y > event.getY(pIndexL)) {
                        movingDownL = false;
                        break;
                    } else if(findDistance(startPointL,
                            new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL))) >= downMinDistance){
                        movingDownL = false;
                    }
                }

                int lnrMinDistance = 50;
                if(movingLeft) {
                    if (Math.abs(oldCoordsL.y - event.getY(pIndexL)) > lnrInaccuracy ||
                            oldCoordsL.x > event.getX(pIndexL)) {
                        movingLeft = false;
                        break;
                    } else if(findDistance(startPointL,
                            new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL))) >= lnrMinDistance) {
                        movingLeft = false;
                        movingSuccessL = true;
                    }
                }

                if(movingRight) {
                    if (Math.abs(oldCoordsR.y - event.getY(pIndexR)) > lnrInaccuracy ||
                            oldCoordsR.x < event.getX(pIndexR)) {
                        movingRight = false;
                        break;
                    } else if(findDistance(startPointR,
                            new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR))) >= lnrMinDistance) {
                        movingRight = false;
                        movingSuccessR = true;
                    }
                }

                if(movingSuccessL && movingSuccessR) {
                    if (!admin_touch)
                    {
                        admin_touch = true;

                        if (callback != null)
                            callback.lTouchSuccess();
                    }
                }

                oldCoordsL = new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL));
                oldCoordsR = new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR));

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                movingDownL = false;
                movingDownR = false;
                movingLeft = false;
                movingRight = false;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private double findDistance(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
    }
}
```

And the use of that:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash);

        layout.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListenerImpl(new TouchListenerImpl.OnLTouch() {
            @Override
            public void lTouchSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(getThis(), "L touched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }));
    }

    public AppCompatActivity getThis(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

Like I said before, the reason you aren't getting any logs may be your hierarchy. Make sure your touch events aren't being consumed by other views on top of yours. To be in the safest side, you should use a FrameLayout as the root element for this kind of behavior, and a boolean variable which allows you to decide if the L listener should be used or not.

Check this for further reference:
https://github.com/fcopardo/EnhancedMapView
If you check the EnhancedMapView file, you'll find this:

```
 public void setOnEnhancedCameraChangeListener(OnEnhancedCameraChangeListener listener){
        if(map!=null){
            map.setOnCameraChangeListener(camera -> {
                if(!isContentTouched() && !isCaptureTouches()){
                    listener.onCameraChange(camera);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is very similar to what you are doing. I suggest you to use a similar approach, a frame layout subclass implementing your L touch listener, and then, use such layout as the root class for your views and activities. Let me know if this helps.